# Wordpress - Image href for home menu nav not working

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have an `image linked to a li element` from a `navbar in wordpress`.

All is working fine but when i hover mouse on image, it also shows a menu element hover in the list.

> How can i hide that when it is linked to the image?

This is the php code for that (from nav-menu-template.php):

```
if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )
    return "<li id='menu-item-1000' class='menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1000'><a class='logo' href='http://razvanwork.esy.es/exelo'><img style='position:absolute;top:-20px;left:-125px;z-index:200;max-width: 402%; ' src='http://razvanwork.esy.es/exelo/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/LogoPrelucrat.png' alt='Exelo' ></a></li>".$items;
```

I attach an image to show what it is doing:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by myself, it was quite simple. I put some text on the href, so it arranged itself in line with the navbar menu. After that, I put position relative for the a href and i floated it left, so I can put the image on top of it with position absolute.

This is the code:

```
$args->theme_location == 'primary' )
    return "<li id='custom-menu-item' class='logo-menu-item'><a style='position:relative;left:-68px' class='logo' href='http://razvanwork.esy.es/exelo'>a<img style='position:absolute;top:-22px;left:-81px;z-index:200;max-width: 402%;' src='http://razvanwork.esy.es/exelo/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/LogoPrelucrat.png' alt='Exelo' ></a></li>".$items;
```